# Genexus CSS3 [attribute*=value] selector

Tags: css, css-selectors, genexus

I want to use the CSS3 `[attribute*=value]` selector, eg:

```
  a[src*="petteni"]{text-align:left;}
```

how can I do it in Genexus Evolution2 Upgrade5?

I'm not able to find such an option in the "Theme editor",
any suggestion is appreciated.

- Genexus version: Ev2 U5
- Environment: Web\Java
- DB: iSeries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a work around to do it:

1. Open your theme
2. Go to the `Custom` node
3. Add a `Class`
4. Use `dummy, a[src*="petteni"]` as name.
5. Set the attributes you want (`text-align:left;`)

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work for me. Trying your workaround Genexus adds a "." (the class identifier) to the name: a[src*="petteni"]. The result is: .a[src*="petteni"] as it was a class identifier and not an element selector. Where I'm wrong? Thanks

Comment: You need to prepend the word `dummy` or anything you want, so the result will be: `.dummy, a[src*="petteni"]` meaning that it will apply to both, the inexistent `.dummy` class and the a `a[src*="petteni"]` selector.

Comment: Ooooook, I perfectly understood your workaround! Simple and smart!!! Thank you very much!